# Connecting to Redis databases via Node in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

About Heroku: App is Nodejs, Express, WebSockets ...
I'm testing an app out on a small free Heroku instance.
I have my own Redis database instances through OpenRedis and RedisToGo.
Those have not been provisioned through Heroku addons but directly from the providers.
I connect to them fine when running locally.  What special do I need to do to connect to them through Heroku?
I was kind of hoping to avoid special Heroku-specific environment variables, but am happy to use them if necessary.
But I definitely need to avoid the necessity of provisioning the Redis addons through Heroku.
Again, I have already my database instances provisioned directly with the relevant providers.

Everything works fine locally under `NODE_ENV=production npm start`, which indicates to my app that it should connect to the remote Redis instances (RedisToGo and/or OpenRedis) instead of the local Redis server.

I'm using Redis for at least three things:

- Session store :: Connect-Redis :: This works fine locally (app server running locally but connecting to remote Redis instance) and also seems to work on Heroku-- I've checked by flushing the database and then pushing a slightly new version to Heroku and the session variable key is refreshed.
- Database :: Node-Redis :: This works fine locally also (also app server running locally but connecting to remote Redis instance for database), but does not seem to be working on Heroku.
- WebSockets Transport Pub/Sub :: I haven't tested this thoroughly.  I'm guessing it's working but it's not important for this question.

What is most interesting to me,

is that the Heroku instance is able to connect to the Redis instance via the Connect-Redis client, but is not able to connect to the same Redis instance via the database client.  Whereas my locally running version is able to connect to the same (remote) instance via both of these clients.  (I have verified these findings through terminal clients, using `flushall` command and waiting for keys to be refreshed.)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I'll post my edits and updates via comments below because they're timestamped.

Comment: Yeah my env switch was bad news as Heroku doesn't set NODE_ENV to production automatically.  Anyways, I got the database to initialise now through Heroku; though still not getting a response on the queries via WebSockets.  More debugging...

Comment: Seems to be getting responses now, but with rather hellish latency.

Comment: Somewhat off topic: why do you use different Redis providers for you instances? Is that for HA?

Comment: I wanted to test as many as I could to compare performance and isolate issues and errors.  Illustrative: A week ago I had only deployed my app to Nodejitsu, and it was failing in spectacular fashion, whilst it was working fine locally.  Their support section urged me to dig deep into my code to locate the bug. The only reason  I deployed to Heroku in the first place was to demonstrate (to myself first of all) that the fault wasn't in my code.  Heroku isn't a long term solution for this app because the way it conceives sessions and state is not compatible with the protocol I'm using. Linode.

Comment: Probably confounding factors were present but I noticed better latency (less) on Rtg vs OpenRedis, and IrisRedis was dysfunctional on that score.  (Nodejitsu also scores dysfunctional.)
On Linode I can run the Redis instance on the same virtual box should be damn fast that way.  We're keeping the Rtg (mini) for backup, diagnostics, &c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out we can't connect to a database (not sure why because I don't know the internals of Heroku's config over AWS) the 'normal' way through Heroku; we need to set the environment variable with the `heroku config:set` command.  OpenRedis provides a terminal ready string, can probably put something similar together for self-provisioned RedisToGo instances, though I haven't done it yet.